# Bootstrap 3 - desktop view on a mobile device

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to show a bootstrap website as the desktop version, when on a mobile device?

Basically the page would show the 992px or 1200px viewports instead of the small devices one.

For example, the [BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk) lets you switch between the mobile and desktop site using a link at the bottom of the page, which is what I would like to do.

Thanks,
Liam

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You Just need to set the Viewport

Make a Link like you said, and this link is a reload of the page but with a `?desktop_viewport=true`, then you can set a Session and as long as that session is set you write this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
```

Instead of this (Responsive version)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

In your `<head>`

Use this as a button

```
<a href="mywebsite.php?show_desktop_mode=true">I want desktop mode!</a>
```

And insert this at the top of your php-file (witch must be loaded on every page)

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_GET['show_desktop_mode'] == 'true') {
    $_SESSION['desktopmode'] = 'true';
}
?>
```

After doing that, you have to change the viewport according to the Sessionvalue by doing this in `<head>`

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['desktopmode'] == 'true') {
    /* DESKTOP MODE */
    ?>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
    <?php
} else {
    // DEFAULT
    ?>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: What kind of Server side scriptlanguage do you use? PHP, Java, asp.NET?

Comment: Thanks @Pinki

This looks like the most straightforward (I have pretty much zero experience of js). 

What do you mean by a session?

So far I've replaced the current viewport meta with `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">` and added a link at the bottom but it does not seem to be changing the layout. Thanks

Comment: It's just a basic HTML page at the moment. I can use asp.Net or PHP

Comment: Is there any reason that this wouldn't work? I've just tried it on a site of ours and I'm still seeing the responsive queries kick in.

Comment: Well you don't remove the responsive queries, you just set the viewport different, and by doing so, you will see the desktop view in the mobile device. But if you pull down your browser window on your desktop, you still see the mobile site.

Comment: @Pinki - is there no way to enforce this on Desktop also?

Comment: Not that i know of, sorry.
That is only possible with javascript.

Comment: Yea this works great. Only visible on mobile/tablet devices, not when resizing broswer window. +1

Answer (score 4):

You could toggle the Bootstrap responsive classes using jQuery.. For example,

```
/* toggle layout */
$('#btnToggle').click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('on')) {
        $('#main .col-md-4').addClass('col-xs-4').removeClass('col-md-4');
        $(this).removeClass('on');
    } else {
        $('#main .col-xs-4').removeClass('col-xs-4').addClass('col-md-4');
        $(this).addClass('on');
    }
});
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/121943

Answer (score 2):

I have been using responsive grid selectors and created desktop view to my page. First, viewport needs to be changed as stated earlier to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
```

but this alone doesn't change behavior of grid selectors. Page is wider in mobile view but it has still mobile layout. To change this, I took a copy from bootstrap.css and named it to bootstrap-non-responsive.css. In this file I changed all the braking points of different views to width of 1 px.

This can be done by changing all the rows with keyword @Media. E.g.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
```

needs to be changed to

```
@media (min-width: 1px) {
```

It's possible to take advantage of multiple replacements of same texts and it's easy and quick to modify css file if you understand how Bootstrap's responsiveness works. It's possible to remove some code from css file too, but it's not necessary, just optimization.

Last I created a link to switch desktop view (used class "hidden-lg"), which created a cookie to save selection of view. If there was a selection of desktop view. I changed normal code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.2.0/css/bootstrap-non-responsive.css" />
```

If desktop view had been selected, I showed link back to mobile view which would remove the cookie and switch to responsive view.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just don't use the Bootstrap responsive grid selectors.

Comment: I do want the site to be responsive by default but I would like a link to give the visitor an option to switch to 'desktop site'

Answer (score 1):

"Turn any fixed-width grid layout into a full-width layout by changing your outermost `.container` to `.container-fluid.`"

The docs say to add the `.container-fluid.` class to make it fluid so by removing it you can stop it being fluid.

you could use jQuery to change the classes.

```
<a id="js-switch">switch to desktop</a>

    <script>
       $("#js-switch").on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            /* Act on the event */
            $("#container-id").removeClass('container-fluid');
            $("#container-id").addClass('container');
       });
    </script>
```