# Twitter Bootstrap 03 Toggle Responsive layout on and off, in mobile version

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building a website with twitter bootstrap 03, can I add a link in mobile version only, that will allow the user to "Show web version" and when he is in web version the link will say "Back to mobile version". I this possible?

Comment: It's possible, but Bootstrap 3 is "mobile-first" so it's always responsive.

Comment: No. I am afraid you cannot. The responsive design is based on the viewport metrics, so it is not possible without rewriting the LESS / CSS that basically will ruin the whole idea with responsive design.

Comment: @davidkonrad that is actually possible

Answer (score 0):

Pls look at my post here

[Bootstrap 3 - desktop view on a mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405816/bootstrap-3-desktop-view-on-a-mobile-device/22407322#22407322)

You have to set this here in a SESSION

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
```

Instead of this (Responsive version)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```