# How can I change the width of Twitter Bootstrap in mobile view to full view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'am very new in web and css and jquery
I know that my question is not interested  but I need help ....
I try to make an bootstrap base web site and I know bootstrap is responsive base 
and after search I found that framework can support non-responsive
after check about bootstrap responsive I found

```
/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }

/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```

now How can I change the width of  Bootstrap in mobile view to full view
I mean when I load my web site by mobile have button such as "Desktop View". and by that l all view and element back it to Large desktop view
I try this after click on link but doesn't work

```
$('body).modal({
    backdrop: true,
    keyboard: true
}).css({
    width: '1201',
    'margin-left': function () {
        return -($(this).width() / 2);
    }
});
```

can you please help me thanks.

Comment: thanks  @joshboley but I ask question

Answer (score 0):

Using just Javascript to switch between mobile and desktop layout is going to be a bit hacky. Especially if you want to remember if the user had selected the view after they close the browser.

However you can still achieve what you want by doing something along the lines of this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Viewport</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'></script>

<button id="mobile">Mobile View</button>
<button id="desktop">Desktop View</button>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#mobile').on('click', function() {
        $('meta[name=viewport]').remove();
        $('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">');
    });
    $('#desktop').on('click', function() {
        $('meta[name=viewport]').remove();
        $('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=1280, initial-scale=1.0">');
    });
</script>
```

I strongly recommend you follow cdonner's link in the comments to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405816/bootstrap-3-desktop-view-on-a-mobile-device) and learn why my solution is not optimal for what you're trying to achieve.