# Change responsive and unresponsive site with button click

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a responsive site with bootstrap 3.1.1. I want to show the desktop view when the user click a button "Desktop view".

I have used [this question right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405816/bootstrap-3-desktop-view-on-a-mobile-device) as the support but this does not help.

It does not help for 2 reasons:-

1. The CSS I have added in my Layout file is as shown:

`<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-device-width: 480px)' href='styles/mobile.css' type='text/css' />`

2. I have used `hidden-xs`, `hidden-sm`, `hidden-md` and `hidden-lg` classes throught out my application.

How can I make the site desktop view and mobile view with the button click?

**EDIT**

I am simultaneously using both the style sheets at the same time. The style sheet for "mobile.css" and "desktop.css" (for the items which doesnot need to be styled specially for mobiles).

SO swapping both the style sheet would not work.

Answer (score 0):

A way: is to use Jquery to change the meta tag for the viewport when the button is clicked:

```
$('#buttonId').click(function (){
        $('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content', "width=1024");
});
```

---

I just thought of something simple. To all you divs that have hidden-xs classes: add a special class (`had-hidden-xs`), for `hidden-lg` add `had-hidden-lg` and so on for every single one of them.

```
//when the button is clicked, every class is removed
$('#buttonId').click(function (){
   //removes all the classes  
   $('.hidden-xs, .hidden-sm, .hidden-md, .hidden-mg').removeClass('hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md  hidden-mg');
});

//when the button to go to mobile view is clicked: 
$('#backToMobile').click(function (){
   //add back your classes using the classes you created in the previous 2 steps
   $('.had-hidden-xs').addClass('hidden-xs');
   $('.had-hidden-sm').addClass('hidden-sm');
   $('.had-hidden-md').addClass('hidden-md');
   $('.had-hidden-lg').addClass('hidden-lg');
});
```

Before Question Edit: Looking at your style sheet, you probably have a style for desktop too since you have a mobile.css. You can easily swap the stylesheets using jquery

```
$('#buttonId').click(function (){
   $('link[href="styles/mobile.css"]').attr('href','desktop.css');
});

$('#buttonId').click(function (){
   $('link[href="style/desktop.css"]').attr('href','mobile.css');
});
```

Comment: Please check the edit. Swapping would not work in these cases. Even if swapping would have worked I would not have been able to come around with the second issue of (hidden classes).

Comment: check my edit @user3328402 . I think the second option deals with both. It will behave just like the question you checked to help solve your problem.

Comment: I tried the method with the question but that didn't help me with the second issue of hidden classes and that is why I posted the question.

Comment: @user3328402 I added how to remove all those classes. you can combine solution and everything will work fine.