# Bootstrap: How to set a viewport to lg even if real screen is smaller ("Classic View")

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, responsive-design

I am designing a responsive webapp using Bootstrap. Of course the XS-Screen has fewer options than the LG-Screen. 
For specialized users, there should be a button to switch to 'Classic/Desktop-View' even if a XS-Smartphone is currently used. (JavaScript to set a virtual viewport size?)

Example: a user on a 320px device can click a button to switch the Html to display the content as if the screen was 1024px wide and scroll around.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add Meta Tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Refer: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-mobile

#### What is Meta element?

Meta element represents any metadata information that cannot be represented by one of the other HTML meta-related elements and Depending on the attributes set

1. name
2. http-equiv
3. charset
4. itemprop

Refer:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta
https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/meta

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I tried setting the width via JavaScript, but Bootstrap's breakpoints remain unchanged (e.g. setting Viewport to 320px in the browser's responsive development mode and then using JavaScript to set width=1024). I would like to achieve that a user on a 320px device can switch the html so display as if the screen was 1024px and scroll around.

Comment: I believe this is second question. raise a new one that would be better. if my answer solved initial your problem

Comment: I now implemented the change of viewport by reloading the page as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405816/bootstrap-3-desktop-view-on-a-mobile-device. This does not work. I even tried the example, http://bbc.com, and it's not working there (just Ctrl-F for Desktop to find the link at the bottom)

Comment: There it is. Our environment is Java, so I used JSP for the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Now I found a solution based on @Venkatraman's response and https://stackoverflow.com/a/22407322/532272 
The important thing is, that a virtual viewport setting is ignored by browser's responsive design tools. You have to test using an actual mobile device.

Here's the code:

#### JavaScript:

```
this.switch2Desktop = function (width) {
    var viewportParam = "viewport=" + width;
    var currentUrlWithoutViewportParam = window.location.href.replace(/[\?\&]+viewport\=\d+/g, '');
    if (currentUrlWithoutViewportParam.contains("?")) {
        window.location.href = currentUrlWithoutViewportParam + "&" + viewportParam;
    } else {
        window.location.href = currentUrlWithoutViewportParam + "?" + viewportParam;
    }
};  

$("#desktopSwitchLink").click(function () {
    responsiveFeatures.switch2Desktop("1024");
});
$("#defaultSwitchLink").click(function () {
    responsiveFeatures.switch2Desktop("0");
});
```

#### JSP:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${param.viewport == '0'}">
        <c:remove var="viewport" scope="session"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${not empty sessionScope.viewport || (not empty param.viewport and param.viewport != '0')}">
        <c:if test="${not empty param.viewport}">
            <c:set var="viewport" value="${param.viewport}" scope="session"/>
        </c:if>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=${sessionScope.viewport}" />
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```