# How to show desktop view on mobile?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsiveness

Hi i want to disable mobile view(responsive) on mobile, i mean when someone visit my site from mobile they should see the desktop version.
I want to show them same on mobile as desktop.
I used some plugin like "mobile smart", "Any theme switcher" but those wasn't work for me.
This theme used bootstrap.
Do you have any idea how i can do this?
my site is [My site](http://wildsunflowerchef.com/)
Thanks

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405816/bootstrap-3-desktop-view-on-a-mobile-device

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable responsiveness:

1. Omit the viewport `<meta>` in your HTML `<head>` tag (`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`)
2. Override the `width` on the `.container` for each grid tier with a
   single width, for example `width: 970px !important;` Be sure that this
   comes after the default Bootstrap CSS. You can optionally avoid the
   `!important` with media queries or some selector-fu.
3. If using navbars, remove all navbar collapsing and expanding
   behavior.
4. For grid layouts, use `.col-xs-*` classes in addition to, or in place
   of, the medium/large ones. Don't worry, the extra-small device grid
   scales to all resolutions.

More info on Bootstrap docs: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive