# Show Mobile Version Of Website Even When accessed from a PC

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am basically a backed developer, i have made a completely working web application using a responsive template available for free, but i want a special thing here,

i want to display mobile version of the website even when accessed from a PC and opens up normally from a mobile device, is that possible, how can i achieve that more essentially where to start ?

below is the image i have made in photoshop for famous gentelella admin theme just to showcase what i want.

[image]

Comment: This answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405816/bootstrap-3-desktop-view-on-a-mobile-device

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a temporary way to view he mobile version? If so, when viewed in chrome use the inspector and switch it to device mode. This will give you a range of mobile device to which you can test the mobile view